# How to remove cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Browser Cookies: When I enter a invalid login Id I get an unauthorized cookie on my HTML page. I display the cookie value, But the cookie seems to a persistent one and it doesn't go even on a page refresh.how do I go about this? I even tried expiring them. It does not work.

Comment: You cannot remove cookie as such. Instead you can only work-around it like setting the cookie value to null. See  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876282/really-deleting-cookies-with-javascript

Comment: I tried all the methods said in the above links.. it creates a duplicate cookie if i try to set it to null

Answer (score 1):

```
document.cookie = 'mycookie=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Comment: thats already done.. despite the fact that the cookie is expired, its shown on the page. Seems more like a persistent cookie